# Laravel 5 Form parameter issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-form

Ok so I have added in the Form functionality just fine in Laravel 5 and have been using it through out these tutorials.  I am brand new to Laravel in general and can't see to find out what is going wrong.  I have a nested route that is todos.items.create, so to create a new item in that list I would have to pass that ID into the Form::open tag.  However when doing so I get a **Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**  Now if I remove the $todo_list->id parameter the page loads fine but with it I always get this error.  Here is my code

Controller:

```
public function create($list_id)
{
    $todo_list = TodoList::findOrFail($list_id);
    return view('items.create', ['TodoList' => $todo_list]);
}
```

Create View (create.blade.php in side my items folder inside the views folder)

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['todos.items.store', $todo_list] )) !!}
```

When just doing the below it renders fine but doing the above which is needed it doesn't.  This is because I need the id of the list in which to create the new item in.

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['todos.items.store'] )) !!}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'TodoListController@index');
Route::resource('todos', 'TodoListController');
Route::resource('todos.items', 'TodoItemController', ['except' => ['index', 'show'] ]);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  I have ran a var_dump of $todo_list->id before the return of the view just to check things and it returned the proper id.

Comment: Can you show us your `todos.item.store` route and any other routes relating to your todo lists?

Comment: I have added the routes, it shouldn't have anything do do with that though as the form renders perfectly fine if the param is removed but like stated is needed to get the id of the correct list to add the item to and send off to the store method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created the $todo_list object but have passed it to your view as $TodoList.

Try using the following instead

```
return view('items.create', ['todo_list' => $todo_list]);
```

When calling the view from the controller, the key used in your array of data is what the variable will be available as on the pages.

Comment: Ok thank you that fixed it!  Never really understood what the key was actually used for but this helps to clarify.